# I am doing testing in Angular 2 but I am facing some error

Tags: angular

```
 describe('BannerComponent (inline template)', () => {

    let comp:    LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
    let de:      DebugElement;
    let el:      HTMLElement;

    it('should display original title', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.signIn);
    });

    it('should display a different test title', () => {
      comp.signIn = 'Test Title';
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(el.textContent).toContain('Test Title');
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ LoginComponent ], // declare the test component
      });

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

      comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

      // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
      de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('./login.component.scss'));
      el = de.nativeElement;
    });
```

Above is my code I wrote but I am facing error like

> Argument of type '(userName: any, password: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected'.
>     Type '(userName: any, password: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ObjectContaining'.
>       Property 'jasmineMatches' is missing in type '(userName: any, password: any) => void'.

Answer (score 0):

Known issue with the latest versions of Typescript/Jasmine. Try explicitly specifying your package version of Typescript for now, perhaps 2.1.6.

Comment: where i need to add perhaps 2.1.6

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? It is located in the DevDepedencies section of your package.json. Please change it to 2.1.6. Then run the "npm update" command from your integrated terminal.

Comment: I am using  "typescript": "~2.5.3" so i need to replace with  "typescript": "~2.1.6"

Comment: Yes (though lets try without the tilde "~", so just 2.1.6) - please give that a try and let us know. You should at least get new and different error messages. Important: After saving those changes, you will need to run "npm install" or "npm update" from your terminal.

Comment: I change the typescript version and i use npm update i facing new issue like:-    Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was just the first issue you were running into. Though for the immediate problem you encountered, that should help move you forward. Out of curiosity what are you seeing now? Note: You will need to create a new question if you have problems with that most likely but mark this one as answered if it addressed the problem so others can view the solution.

Comment: Thank you for creating new problem

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice you posted the issue. Yeah, that did not work properly. It seems that somehow your install did not succeed. Please re-run npm install. WebPack is looking for typescript 2.0.2 or greater (which 2.1.6 should satisfy). So it seems somehow your install did not work. Please let me know the result. We should be able to get these dependencies worked out without much issue.

Comment: If npm update is failing, please try npm install. This should fetch us fresh copies of all package dependencies.